# How to add options to the Task Bar java

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace, taskbar

I am making a Java application and i was just wondering if there is any way to add different options to the box that opens when you right click on an icon on the Windows Task Bar (not sure what it's called)

[image]

That's what it usually looks like (In Windows 10) when you right click on the icon in the task bar but i want to add my own options like steam has

[image]

Is there any way to do that? If it requires external library's could you please link them? Thanks anyway.